# How can I fetch Clash Of Clans API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to do a discord bot with the clash of clans api. But I get a weird error message. Thanks

Error Message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>v1/clans/LYVVC9JQQ</Key><RequestId>67H6BCRSJ41W6K6X</RequestId><HostId>mPhpqkXy1qKENdOnt+CPhfQn4rK0hGhaMxaLq9q21Ehtbs/CMzSgqHy9TA6L7hii0PY9+Lo2rzg=</HostId></Error>
```

```js
async function getClashofClansAPi() {
    let clashofClansAPI = await fetch(`https://developer.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/LYVVC9JQQ`)
    let cocApi = await clashofClansAPI.text()
    console.log(cocApi)
}
getClashofClansAPi()
```

Comment: Is the API not at `api.clashofclans.com`?

Comment: (Noting that your fetch appears to lack any form of authorization.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API URL is `api.clashofclans.com` and you are also lacking an API KEY in your authorization header unless you removed it for security purposes

> Clash of Clans API uses JSON Web Tokens for authorizing the requests.
> Tokens are created by developers on My Account page and must be passed
> in every API request in Authorization HTTP header using Bearer
> authentication scheme. Correct Authorization header looks like this:
> "Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN".

Answer (score 0):

The request url should be https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/%232Q8GRY8LQ

Remember, the hashtag (for example #2PP) should be replaced with %23,
Next time, please read Clash of Clans API Documentation correctly.